# google maps API v3 not working with cordova

Tags: google-maps-api-3, cordova

I'm trying to use the google maps on an Android app. I include the Google Maps API with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api /js?key=my key&sensor=false"></script>
```

Every website is whitelisted with

```
<access origin=".*"/>
```

in the .xml.

But i still get an error

```
Uncaught referenceError:google is not defined
```

So, the API couldn't be loaded. 
The code works perfectly when running on my PC but this happen when I put it on the mobile device, showing that the problem may come from cordova.

My device of course has an internet connection, any idea on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is just a typo, but you have a space in your url, and now I believe the url is: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=yourkey&sensor=false

Comment: the space appeared when copy-pasting the code in the question, it is not present in my actual code. The url I use is the one given by google in the doc, it is supposed to work and it does work when running the code in a browser

Comment: Ok - both URL's should work - the googleapi url is newer.  Are you developing an App, or a website to be viewed?  There is a different api key for an android app:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2 - Also, if it's as a website, can you dig into the error on the browser xhr (https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging)?